# How to determine birth week in current year for 7 day coupon

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to get my customers birth dates, but with the current year(sysdate).  For example, John Brown was born in 01-JAN-65, I would like to create a query that retrieves the previous Monday and next Sunday from John's birthday, so that the customer can see that their coupon is valid between that seven day time frame.  So for John Brown, the row would have three columns

```
FullName,       Monday         Sunday
John Brown      31-DEC-2012    06-JAN-2013
```

My table definition is:

**Table Name** - Customers

**Columns**

```
Customer_ID
First_Name
Last_Name
DOB
Phone
```

I have read Oracle Database 11g's chapter 5 "Storing and Processing Dates and Times", but did not find a solution to my problem.  Please help, thank you.  I will send 5$ to your PayPal email as appreciation for helping me, I am trying to learn.

I have tried to implement code from [How do I get the current year using SQL on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119710/how-do-i-get-the-current-year-using-sql-on-oracle?rq=1) but I keep getting errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the [NEXT_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions106.htm) function.

```sql
with sourceData as (
  select 'John Brown' FullName, DATE '1965-01-1' BirthDate 
  from dual
), BirthDatesThisYear as
(
  select 
    FullName,
    Add_Months(BirthDate, (extract(YEAR from sysdate)- extract(YEAR from birthdate))*12) BirthDateThisYear
  from sourceData
)
select 
  FullName,
  NEXT_DAY(BirthDateThisYear-8,'MON') PreviousMonday,
  NEXT_DAY(BirthDateThisYear-8,'MON')+6 NextSundayFromPrevMonday
from BirthDatesThisYear;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions106.htm) for your testing.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution worked.  Please send me your PayPal email as promised.  Thanks again =)

Comment: I'm glad to help, no need for PayPal.  I did it for all those who have helped me.  Pass it on and help another please.

Comment: @JamesHenrick - If you still willing to spend $5, consider sending it to the author of `SQL Fiddle`. There is a `Donate` button in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 1):

One query using Oracle's `TO_CHAR`, `TO_DATE`, and `NEXT_DAY`:

```
SELECT name, 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(birthdate, 'MMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD') "This Birthday",
       NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(birthdate, 'MMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'Sun') "Sunday After",
       NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(birthdate, 'MMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'Sun') - 6 "Monday Before"
FROM Table1;
```

Here's [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3763/16) with my test data.

Comment: @A.B.Cade - Yep. You definitely have a point here.  I literally followed OP's logic and didn't think about such case.