# Extract only the current year in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to get the current year from the oracle db. For an example I need to return 2017 as the answer for the current year as a number type. I tried using following way.

```
select to_Number(sysdate, 'YYYY') from student s
```

But it not works. So what is the easiest way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current year using SQL on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119710/how-do-i-get-the-current-year-using-sql-on-oracle)

Answer (score 10):

You need `to_char` instead of to_number

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from student;
```

That give a string though. you could apply `to_number` on it further to convert into number.

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')) from student;
```

But there is better method using [`extract`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639):

```
select extract(year from sysdate) from student;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use  [`extract`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

```
select extract(year from sysdate)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

get current year  start date:
*trunc (sysdate, 'yyyy')*

```
select trunc (sysdate, 'yyyy'),SYSDATE from dual;
```

get current Month start date:

```
select trunc (sysdate, 'mm'),SYSDATE from dual;
```

select records in a month/year:

```
created_date between trunc (sysdate, 'mm') and sysdate;

created_date between trunc (sysdate, 'yyyy') and sysdate;
```