# How to get current Year in PLSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to get current year using `YEAR(GETDATE())`:

```
DECLARE
    currentYear PLS_INTEGER := YEAR(GETDATE());
BEGIN
    WHILE startYear <= currentYear LOOP
        someOperation.......
        .....
        ....

    LOOP END;
END;
```

When I execute this I get the below as script O/P

> ORA-06550: line 15, column 28:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'YEAR' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 15, column 13:
>   PL/SQL: Item ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 21, column 21:
>   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
>   ORA-06550: line 21, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

I see if I use `SELECT YEAR(GETDATE)` results in returning the current year.

Any suggestions how can I get the current year?

Comment: I do not see `startYear` defined, and `YEAR()` is not a valid Oracle SQL function, nor a valid PL/SQL function.  Same with `GETDATE`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982 and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-640DB3AA-15AF-4825-BD6C-1D4EB5AB7715

Comment: The error message *"identifier 'YEAR' must be declared"* seems pretty clear. Declare functions called 'YEAR' and 'GETDATE'.

Comment: Don't declare the `YEAR` and `GETDATE` functions; use the appropriate Oracle functions rather than trying to use functions for another RDBMS. As the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119898/1509264) states, use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)` ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=15dd6174c673cb5a405807ae6a3da186)).

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few options.

```
SQL> select
  2    to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') year_1,
  3    --
  4    extract (year from sysdate) year_2
  5  from dual;

YEAR     YEAR_2
---- ----------
2019       2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `YEAR` is a SQL Server function. You could use `SYSDATE` as so.

```
DECLARE
  currentYear PLS_INTEGER := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'));
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(currentYear);
END;
```